# como hacer test para clases anidadas?

Tags: java-ee, test, junit, clase-anidada

apenas empiezo con esto de los @test , alguien me podría ayudar solo con un ejemplo para el siguiente caso, pues dentro de la cobertura tambien me pide cubrir esta clase, ya intente varias cosas pero no. GRACIAS

```
public class MappersVars{

 private MappersVars(){}

 public static class A{
    public static final String NUEVO_EJEMPLO="NUEVO_EJEMPLO";
    public static final String HOLA="HOLA";
    ...
 }

  public static class B{
    public static final String SALUDO="SALUDO";
    public static final String VALOR="VALOR";
    ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Las pruebas unitarias verifican la correctitud del codigo y en tu caso no lo hay, las declaraciones de variables no se pueden verificar

Comment: gracias , es lo que me comentan que no se debe testear esa parte , cuando haga algún test de algo que ocupe eso me marcara como cubierta esta parte.